# What does F= or F=a=> mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been pursuing the **[codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)** site lately with a focus on Javascript. I keep seeing something that I don't understand and can't find an answer to. Check out **[this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32015/are-you-in-the-biggest-room#answer-32023)**. The first line starts with `F=a=>`. I assume that this is a shorthand function declaration, but I can't find any reference to it elsewhere on the web. Can someone explain, or point me to a good document about this syntax?

*Feel free to tag this question. Hard to tag when I don't know what I'm looking at.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the ES6 definition document this is the [Arrow function](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions) symbol

Looking at [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) this is just shorthand for declaring an anonymous function

An interesting difference is that the arrow function syntax provides a closure so (quoting from MDN)

> In ECMAScript 3/5, this issue was fixed by assigning the value in this
>   to a variable that could be closed over.

```
function Person() {
  var self = this; // Some choose `that` instead of `self`. 
                   // Choose one and be consistent.
  self.age = 0;

  setInterval(function growUp() {
    // The callback refers to the `self` variable of which
    // the value is the expected object.
    self.age++;
  }, 1000);
}
```

> Alternatively, a bound function could be created so that the proper
>   this value would be passed to the growUp function.
>
> Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context, so
>   the following code works as expected.

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

In those two examples you can see the difference very clearly

```
function() {
    console.writeline('es5');
}
```

versus

```
   () => {
       console.writeline('es6');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, that is a shorthand for a function declaration.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions